# Any way to access command line when desktop freezes?

Tags: 12.04, freeze

Occasionally Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit on my Panasonic CF-51 laptop will freeze up. The mouse cursor can still be moved, but I cannot access anything and no shortcut keys seem to work. Is there any way to access the terminal when this happens?

Comment: You can ask a separate question and perhaps address the crashing issue.

Comment: I thought I might try and access logs or something and then see what help I can get through a question. This happens infrequently enough that I don't have any real information at this point to provide for a useful question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be able to access the command line only interface by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> and then typing your short username (it has no spaces, is all lowercase) and password to login. Then you have a full screen terminal that is not dependent on the GUI.

You may be able to restart the graphical interface by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Sysrq</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> and then <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Sysrq</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>. Be forewarned though that will log out any graphical sessions so you will loose any unsaved work in the GUI, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can access the terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> through <kbd>F12</kbd>. This is called a "tty" terminal. "tty" stands for "[teletype](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=833765&p=5216012#post5216012)". The keyboard shortcut will not get you to a terminal, but to a login prompt. Once you log in with your normal user name and password (which will not appear), you will then be taken to a bash prompt.

Comment: Ctrl Alt F1 not responding